# file_get_contents not working with variable PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

My PHP version is 5.6.40.
I have a variable, in which I want to store an image url.

```
$imageurl = "http://i132.photobucket.com/albums/q13/animalhelper2006/1376.jpg";
```

And I'm using `file_get_contents` function to get this image.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($imageurl);
```

But it does not work, it shows empty result. But when I tried to directly load image url, it worked.

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://i132.photobucket.com/albums/q13/animalhelper2006/1376.jpg");
```

What's wrong? please help.

Thanks

Comment: Not reproducible, I get the same results for both, as expected.

Comment: @CBroe strange, the second way worked for me, but of course I need to use variable.

Comment: Make sure your variable contains _exactly_ what you think it should, make a var_dump of it, and look at what string length that reports. Make sure there’s no additional whitespace or other unprintable characters at either side of it.

Comment: @CBroe you're right, I'm used var_dump and see the length is different. After many checking I found the variable is hex code http&#58;//i132&#46;photobucket&#46;com/albums/q13/animalhelper2006/1376&#46;jpg 
Final I used html_entity_decode function and it working fine now.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow @CBroe way. I'm used var_dump and see the length is different. After many checking I found the variable is hex code `http&#58;//i132&#46;photobucket&#46;com/albums/q13/animalhelper2006/1376&#46;jpg`
Final I used html_entity_decode function and it working fine now.

```
$contents = file_get_contents(html_entity_decode($imageurl));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might come from file name which is included space (" ").
You can try using urlencode file name before parsing it into file_get_contents.

Comment: Thanks, After many checking I found the variable is hex code http&#58;//i132&#46;photobucket&#46;com/albums/q13/animalhelper2006/1376&#46;jpg 
Final I used html_entity_decode function and it working fine now.